# Technical translation for "stream" as a programming concept

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

As a Java developer, I use [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) almost every day.

Up until now, I've just called them *streams* but with a Spanish accent, i.e. `/estrims/`.

> El problema estaba en que el primer *estrim* estaba lanzando un segundo *estrim* sin pasarle los valores de los *zredlocal*.

I'm sure I'm not the only Spanish dev to season my day-to-day Spanish with some technical English terms here and there -- actually, I've yet to find anybody who calls streams anything other than `/estrims/` :)

Today, however, I tried to replace it with a Spanish term instead, and I felt a bit puzzled. *Corrientes*? Ugh, that doesn't sound right. *Secuencias*? Too generic. *Flujos*? Hmm... Not convincing enough.

Hey, I know! I'll check [Oracle's own Spanish version of their documentation on Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/procesamiento-streams-java-se-8-2763402-esa.html):

> #### Procesamiento de datos con streams de Java SE 8 - Parte 1
>
> **Uso de operaciones de streams para expresar consultas de procesamiento de datos complejas**
>
> (...) Los diseñadores de la interfaz API de Java han incorporado en su actualización una nueva abstracción denominada *Stream*, que permite procesar datos de modo declarativo. Más aún, los streams permiten aprovechar las arquitecturas de núcleos múltiples sin necesidad de programar líneas de código multiproceso. Suena bien, ¿no? Eso es lo que exploraremos en esta serie de artículos.
>
> Antes de ahondar en lo que se puede hacer con streams, veamos un ejemplo para tener una idea del nuevo estilo de programación que posibilitan los streams de Java SE 8.

Bummer. Turns out even they didn't know what to call them in Spanish either!

So... **What would *you* call a Java stream in Spanish?**

Comment: Si propongo _concatenación_ de funciones probablemente demuestre que no entiendo una jota del concepto, pero es en lo primero en que pensé al mirar ejemplos. En todo caso, parece que "Stream" es un nombre de fantasía que lamentablemente se solapa sobre el otro _stream_ tradicional de la programación, simplemente "flujo".

Comment: We call them "flujos" where I work, but we're referring to streaming video rather than Java's streams.

Comment: Oh, are Java's streams a form of "Fluent interface" / "Interfaz fluida" (cf. Wikipedia)? If they are then maybe that term would work?

Comment: @walen maybe you're suffering from "semantic satiation" (where a word starts to look wrong or weird when you fixate on it for a while) :-D 
And, thinking about it some more, I think I've heard some people here at work use *estrim* as well as *flujo*, but maybe they're referring to something else..I'll have to ask them. 
(As a native English speaker working full-time in Spanish, I learn something new every day! Some things I've had to unlearn - eg. "correo electronico", no-one actually says that.)

Comment: As a german programmer, fluent in english, living in a spanish speaking country I am impressed how german is adapting "anglicism" in comparision to spanish. I guess there is no german programmer on the whole world who could even invent this question.

Comment: @MarcWittke - So what do you call "stream" in German?

Comment: Just brainstorming here -- *racha*?

Comment: Interesting that you mention German Vs Spanish at adapting Anglicisms. English has a scarce vocabulary and recycling words or resorting to contorted allegories is often necessary in order to convey a new concep like streams. German, OTOH has beautifully constructed complex nouns that convey intricate concepts with elegant simplicity, such is the case of *zeitgeist* or *Das Ich*: there are no single nouns in either `en` or `es`  that convey the full idea elegantly. "French was made to talk about love, German about science, English about horses and Spanish was made to talk about God." I've heard

Comment: I checked French and found that one of the two translations is *suite de données*.  It seems to me that *suite* is nicer to say in Spanish than *estrim*.  So maybe "suite de datos" or if the context is clear, then just "suite." // Another idea: *corriente*?

Comment: @aparente001: as you can see in the de facto standard dictionary (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Streaming), even non-programmers are comfortable with the English term. There is no common translation. All German programmers I know prefer to read technical literature in English, since translations done by non programmers tend to contain word no one knows nor understands

Comment: @MarcWittke - So you're saying that "stream" (in the programming world) has *not* been translated to German?

Comment: @aparente001, yes, like the majority of english terms in this context

Comment: Recuerdo hace años que IBM en el sistema operativo y los manuales de AS-400 lo tradujo literalmente como "arroyos". Jamás he visto cosa más ininteligible en mi vida que aquellos manuales.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Oracle themselves use **"stream"** in their documentation, I assume we could use it as a loanword with no further problem. That is what I usually do in my job.

Anyway, if we are committed to finding a proper translation, I like ***flujo***; I think *"un flujo de datos"* is an easy to understand concept for a Spanish speaker (programmer or not), which should be the main purpose when using the term.

In case you don't find it very convincing, as you said, you might prefer to use ***transmisor***. WordReference translates "stream" as a verb to *'transmitir'* when talking about data. I personally like *flujo* better than *transmisor*.

Comment: Entiendo que por sus otras acepciones, quizá al principio 'flujo' sea incómodo de usar en un entorno profesional. Pero yo lo veo especialmente útil para usarlo con gente no experta en ellos, como a la hora de enseñar a estudiantes de informática. Me parece bastante visual.

Answer (score 5):

"Flujo" o "corriente" deberían de ser los conceptos correctos.

El concepto de *stream* se basa en que se trata de un tipo de dato que recibe información desde una fuente para poder ser manipulada.

Y este concepto encaja en varios métodos usados junto al ***stream***, como **`streamRead`** que yo lo traduciría como "lectura de flujo": en este tipo de lectura, en lugar de enviarte el texto entero, te envía el texto en pedazos, iniciando el "**flujo**" desde el inicio de un texto.

Answer (score 3):

***Corriente***

*Flujo* is "flow". If I were reading a technical text and met with *flujo* or *flujo de datos*, I'd have no idea what it would be talking about; it's too generic. Simply passing an argument to a function counts as *flujo de datos*.

I've always thought of a stream in any programming language as being an analogy with a water stream. It's passing a big mass of some fluid thing (e.g. water, a network connection, a file) in undefined, variable sized chunks at a time. I think ***corriente*** fits better.

When I'm in a spot where I want to stay strictly in Spanish, I prefer to choose the best translation of the loanword as-is, striving to keep the original analogy, instead of thinking of something new for the concept.

Comment: Good answer! Nice to have you around, welcome to [spanish.se]!

Comment: Great answer! However I disagree that *flujo de datos* gives no clue to its meaning in computer programming. In fact, Computer Science 101 introduces  **control de flujo** right after defining "algorithm" as a step by step recipe for transforming data. The association is immediate "what is this "flowing stuff" that is being "controlled in on it's flow in order to be transformed? Why it's data! Naturally, a Data Flow and a Control Flow define the algorithm. Add math to write it down formally. The next step in the allegory is of course a *cascade* control flow that begets Top-down Programming

Comment: @hlecuanda I didn't mean it was meaningless as if it couldn't be applied to programming. I meant it's meaningless in that it can be applied to too many things. If you tell me the method you use to get from city A to city B is "traveling", while it must be technically true, how is that meaningful? It would be more informative to say "driving" or "flying". Same thing, data flow does not only work with streams, it also works with the flow of data from one function to another via an argument or a return value or an assignment to a variable in a shared scope, basically anything.

Comment: Oh I see, what you mean is that *flujo de datos* while technically accurate, lacks the precision to correctly describe java streams. That being the case I agree with you. It's a classical case of accuracy vs precision. Accuracy gets you in the ballpark, precision throws a strike, speaking in baseball terms.

Answer (score 2):

Además de la respuesta de "flujo" ya dada en otras dos respuestas (que en particular me gusta porque, al conectar a un flujo de datos, muchas veces se hace por medio de canales y puertas, así manteniendo una firme y coherente conexión con la terminología tanto informática como no informática; y cuando hay que hacer un pequeño *buffer*, allí la palabra "reserva", también con uso hidrólogo y fluvial, serviría muy bien), otras posibilidades según el contexto podrían ser:

- **corriente**
  Ya mencionado por Mike, apenas hay diferencia en significado con "flujo", siendo muy sustituible en contextos no informáticos por esa otra.
- **fuente**
  Desafortunadamente, es una palabra muy general, aunque podría valer para ciertas cosas (como tal vez un `Supply` en Perl6).
- **canal**
  También de terminología fluvial, es lo que contiene los datos, por lo que valdría siempre que no sea preciso distinguir los datos de su vía (lo normal es que cada canal lleve una sola serie de datos, por lo que sin tener los flujos fundidos (*muxed*) serían efectivamente sinónimos). Por ende podríamos también utilizar palabras como **zanja**, **caz** o **conducto**.
- **transmisión / transmisor**
  Como fuente, también tiene connotaciones diferentes a pesar de describir también la acción (es decir, la transmisión la veo más como el conjunto total de los datos, y no las partes de los mismos en tránsito). Además, a mí no me cuela hablar de una transmisión dentro de un mismo ordenador (tendría que ser algo remoto), pero sí existen *streams* dentro de un solo sistema. En la forma '-or', incluso suena como si hablara del sistema del que provienen los datos.

Comment: Joder, acabo de leer más sobre Streams en Java y veo que no tienen nada que ver con los *streams* tradicionales.  A ver si edito esta respuesta más.

Comment: ¿Como no son como streams tradicionales? Si te refieres a como los de C para leer archivos, la analogía sigue ahí, es solo que Java hizo que streams funcionara con más cosas aparte de archivos. Se trata de trabajar con un cuerpo grande de datos un pedazo a la vez, sin tener que cargar el cuerpo entero.

Comment: @guifa No te preocupes. En java nada es lo que parece. De hecho no es un lenguaje de programación. Es una mistica lengua alienígena usada en su planeta de origen para discutir sobre política, pues insultos y meledicencias pasan por la mente de quién lo hablé sin necesidad de expresarlas y causar sentimientos heridos. Casualmente es trivial para dichos alienígenas implementar la máquina virtual que lo interpreta en la arquitectura x86. Todo lo demás es mercadotecnia de Oracle convenciendo a la industria de dicho lenguaje es aplicable para cualquier tipo de aplicacion. Y aquí estamos

Comment: @JoL Creo que estás confundiendo los *streams* de Java de tipo `InputStream` y `OutputStream` y la monad `Stream` que tiene poco (si tiene algo) que ver con los otros.  Efectivamente se trata de una colección de elementos que se puede evaluar de forma perezosa al mandarle varias operaciones que además pueden ser realizadas de forma paralela.  La idea es que puedo, por ejemplo, hacer un listado de palabras, y crear de él un `Stream` al que aplico un filtro por las palabras que empiecen con vocal y una operación por las palabras en mayúscula …

Comment: …y luego si pido el quinto elemento, en teoría aunque tendrá que hacer el filtro para saber cuál es el quinto elemento, no tendrá que poner todas las palabras en mayúscula, solo el quinto.  Con un bucle *for* tradicional, habría que poner todas las palabras en mayúscula primero.  Como ves, es muy diferente de los `Input/OutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Pues mira, te voy a dar una propuesta basada en otro lenguaje de programación: C#. Los *streams* de Java permiten al programador hacer con las colecciones más o menos lo mismo que la API de Linq permite hacer en C# con los objetos que implementen la interfaz `IEnumerable`. Así que aquí va la propuesta:

> **[enumeración](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FqoohpP)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. enumeratio, -ōnis.
> ```
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de enumerar.
> 2. f. Expresión sucesiva de las partes de que consta un todo, de las especies que comprende un género, etc.
> 3. f. Cómputo o cuenta numeral de las cosas.

Así, un *stream* sería un *enumerador*, que no hay que confundir con un *iterador*.

Comment: @walen bueno, por intentarlo que no quede. :-)

Comment: Sí estoy con walen, enumerador me parece algo bien distinto (obviamente gran parte del problema es que tantos términos informáticos representan cosas casi idénticos salvo un pequeño pormenor aquí u otro detalle allí y por ello es difícil siempre encontrar un equivalente que mantenga todas aquellas diferencias mínimas.  E incluso entre idiomas de programación esas palabras pueden tener significados muy particulares a aquellos idiomas.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que los `Stream` de Java son cosas bien diferentes de los *streams* tradicionales, yo propondría una palabra bastante diferente.

La idea con los `Stream` de Java es que puedes tomar una colección de datos, aplicarle algunas operaciones que no se ejecutan de forma inmediata, y acabar con una nueva colección de datos que, al acceder uno de sus elementos, se calcula solo entonces.

Lo bueno de aquello es poder procesar cada elemento paralelamente, así aprovechandose de varios hilos.  Empiezas con una lista, y al convertirla en un *stream*, sigue funcionando básicamente como una lista, hasta que al final la conviertes en algo (que igual puede ser un `List`). Así, en términos técnicos, tal vez lo podríamos llamar una representación perezosa de una lista con procesamiento paralelo.

Si queremos mantener una jerga fluvial, propondría **catarata**, porque permite el procesamiento de grandes cantidades de datos, filtrando, aplicando operaciones, etc.

Tal vez sería adecuado llamarlo un **curador**, porque curia la lista de que son oriundos los datos de acuerdo con algunas ciertas indicaciones. No creo que se utilice en otros contextos, aunque *curador* como tal tiene varios significados (por formarse tanto de *curar* como *curiar*).

Y para emplear jerga de fabricación, podríamos llamarlo un **ensamblador**, porque también funciona como una línea de ensamble: cada elemento se procesa individualmente, de acuerdo con algunos pasos. No obstante, eso podría entrar en conflicto con el *lenguaje ensamblador*, que es otra cosa muy distinta.